# How can I set up cron so it stores its output locally for me to read with mail?

Tags: cron, mail

I have a cronjob setup on my machine. Sometimes, this job misbehaves. I'd like to read its output locally with the `mail` unix program.

If I attempt to run `mail`, command-not-found suggests I install `mailutils`, and when I do, Ubuntu starts a wonderful journey into setting up an actual SMTP server. [Eeeeek!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OXQpQ7OZw0U)

I just want my "mail" to sit in /var/spool or whatever.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I know I can run `journalctl` to learn that my jobs have been failing, but that doesn't capture the reason why they have.

Comment: So do you want to actually mail yourself a log? Also, to store the output, go to where you stored the cronjob and edit the line that looks like `my_command_to_run` to `my_command_to_run >> /path/to/log/file` and it will write the output to that file. For you, this is an unnecessary step, as you can just do `my_command_to_run | mail -s "Subject" example@domain.com` to get the same result, unless you want the actual log file stored for other uses besides reading for mail. Mail requires you to name your computer something in order for it to send mail, so you have to go through the setup.

Comment: Would it be easier to modify the job to send you a notification message. I haven't tried it myself but I'll play with it tonight.

Comment: This might be a good starting point: [Minimal MTA that delivers mail locally (for cron)?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82093/minimal-mta-that-delivers-mail-locally-for-cron)